# Can I apply a background colour on a dropdown in Microsoft Edge using only CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have created [this page with a download form](https://formever.com/download), and it includes a dropdown that is styled using CSS. This is what it looks like in Firefox and Chrome, where it is working as hoped:

[image: dropdown style working]

In **Microsoft Edge**, the dropdown is essentially invisible, though, and I think it's because the background colour is not rendering. It looks like this:

[image: dropdown style not visible in edge]

If you click in the area where the dropdown is, it then becomes partially visible:

[image: dropdown style when selected in edge]

I have looked at [other answers on Stack Overflow about styling in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=IE%20css%20dropdown), but it's not entirely clear to me why the background is not rendering. Some answers indicate I need to place styling directly on the `option` element, and other answers use Javascript with a `ul` element.

If possible, I'd like to use a pure CSS solution. I don't need to support IE 8 or below, only IE 9 and above, including Edge.

This is the CSS, in SASS format, that I am using:

```
.drop-down {
    display: block;
    -webkit-appearance: none;  /*REMOVES DEFAULT CHROME & SAFARI STYLE*/
    -moz-appearance: none;  /*REMOVES DEFAULT FIREFOX STYLE*/
    border: 0 !important;  /*REMOVES BORDER*/
    margin-top: .5em;
    color: white;
    font-size:1em;
    padding: .4em 2em .4em .6em;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-size: 1em;
    background: $formever_blue url(dropdown_arrow.png) no-repeat;
    background-position-x: calc(100% - 0.5em);
    background-position-y: center;
}
.download-form .drop-down {
    font-size: 2em;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**How can I make the dropdown style in Edge match how it appears in Firefox?**

Answer (score 0):

You can change **calc(100% - .5em)** in your background property to fixed value. Or add another background property without calc before current special for IE.

**Update:**

```
background: $color url() no-repeat;
background-position-x: calc(100% - 0.5em);
background-position-y: center;
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. I tried replacing `calc(100% - .5em)` with a fixed value, and moving `background-color` to a separate declaration. Neither seem to have solved the problem though. Are you saying that Edge does not accept `calc` declarations?

Comment: I think edge doesn't accept calc in this or some other complex declaration. In simple things like width it will work well.

Comment: Btw, you can try to use `background-position-x` for `calc`, I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the updated code. I've updated my question to include how I have the CSS now, which is based on your answer. Unfortunately, when I load the page in Edge, on my computer, the drop down menu is still invisible as described.